# struts1 ognl static method call

Tags: java, struts, struts-1

I've been trying googling from past some time, but seems like I'm unable to hit the right phrase.

I wanted to know is static method calling supported in struts1. If yes, then how to configure it ? Make some changes in struts-config.xml ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no OGNL in Struts 1.

You can use standard JSP custom tag functionality which includes calling functions.

Comment: that would be like creating a taglib, right ? Is there any other small procedure/way for achieving what I want.

Comment: @XCoder you could call the function on the Java side, and put the value into the request. JSP-based custom tags are easy. Modern JSP makes it easy to call functions. There are many options.

Answer (score 0):

You can't configure `Action` or `ForwardAction` to use the method other that `execute`. To execute other methods you need a `DispatchAction` that only call method dynamically.

Comment: seems like I was unable to explain my issue. Struts2 ognl has a feature to call static methods from within JSP, I'm asking is this same possible in Struts1.

Comment: Would you explain what do you mean "static methods"?